# How to Read all files contained in a directory (WINDOWS)

Tags: c++

I need to transfer all the files contained in a directory.

How should I proceed to read all the files in a specific directory and then transfer via socket?

**EDIT:**
I have no problems with the transfer,
just do not know what should I do to download a complete directory.

Comment: What part do you have trouble with? Getting the directory listing? Sending the files? Both of those depends on the operating system you're on. On POSIX systems (like Linux and OSX) you can use [`opendir`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/opendir.html) and [`readdir`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/readdir.html). On Windows you can use [`FindFirstFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364418%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`FindNextFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364428%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: i transfer file by file.. 
I need to transfer an entire folder.

Comment: I have no problems with the transfer,
just do not know what should I do to download a complete directory

Comment: As for sending a file, on Linux read about [`sendfile`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sendfile.2.html). On OSX you have the similarly named (but ultimately different) [`sendfile`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/sendfile.2.html). On Windows you have [`TransmittFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740565%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: So what you really care about is iterating over the names of all the files in a particular directory? [From what you've said, presumably once you do that, you know how to transfer each file, correct?]

Comment: Please read my first comment again, it contains all information you need: What functions to use and links to official references. As for how to use them, there are thousands of examples all over the Internet (including in the references).

Comment: TransmittFile, It seems interesting  thanks!

Comment: For finding the file names, I would *not* recommend `opendir`/`readdir` or `FindFirstFile`/`FindNextFile`. I'd prefer (for one example) the much nicer, cleaner interface provided by a Boost `directory_iterator`. For example: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/filesystem/example/simple_ls.cpp

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple version to get you started since, if I understood correctly, your only trouble is in retrieving a listing of files rather than transferring them. With a bit of recursion, you can also descend into the subdirectories and fetch a complete listing all in one go (easy enough to modify this example).

```
// Returns files in the specified directory path.
vector<wstring> list_files(wstring path)
{
    vector<wstring> subdirs, matches;
    WIN32_FIND_DATA ffd;
    HANDLE hFind = FindFirstFile((path + L"\\*.*").c_str(), &ffd);
    if (hFind != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        do
        {
            wstring filename = ffd.cFileName;
            if (!(ffd.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY))
                matches.push_back(path + L"\\" + filename);
        } while (FindNextFile(hFind, &ffd) != 0);
    }
    FindClose(hFind);
    return matches;
}
```

Example:

```
vector<wstring> files = list_files("C:\\pr0n");
// 'files' now contains 1,000 file entries. 
// Directories are not included.
// Now send them over individually.
```

Note that there are better, cross-platform alternatives if you're interested such as boost FS.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example code from [MDSN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scx99850(VS.80).aspx) but I modified it a bit as you
just want to get all the files from the current directory.
I am assuming you are using MFC.  If not refer to this [listing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365200(v=vs.85).aspx).

```
void Recurse(LPCTSTR pstr)
{
   CFileFind finder;

   // build a string with wildcards
   CString strWildcard(pstr);
   strWildcard += _T("\\*.*");

   // start working for files
   BOOL bWorking = finder.FindFile(strWildcard);

   while (bWorking)
   {
      bWorking = finder.FindNextFile();

      // skip . and .. files; otherwise, we'd
      // recur infinitely!

      if (finder.IsDots())
         continue;

      if (!finder.IsDirectory())
      {         
          CString str = finder.GetFilePath();
          AfxMessageBox( str );
      }
   }

   finder.Close();
}
```

To use it, call:

```
Recurse(_T("C:\\intel"));
```